# MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.'

Tags: java, mongodb, connection

I'm using Java 11 (Maven project) for mongodb Free Tier Cluster (Version 4.0.13). I'm trying to connect via connection-string (for 3.6 drivers or later) like:

```
mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

and by the same way via connection-string (for 3.4 driver or later):

```
mongodb://user:pass@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I've already tested different dependencies for java drivers like:  mongodb-driver-sync (ver. 3.11.0), mongodb-driver-sync (ver. 3.10.0) , mongodb-driver-sync (ver. 3.8.0).

Maven dependency looks like this:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Also I tried to use `mongo-java-driver` via connection-string for `3.6 or later drivers/3.4 or later` and versions like: 3.11.0, 3.10.0, 3.8.0, 3.7.0.

Maven dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I'm getting always the same issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000: 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.' on server cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.", "code" : 8000, "codeName" : "AtlasError" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:164)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:286)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:247)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:34)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:91)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:51)
```

My current POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>    
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>project.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas how to solve the issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Java 8**

I've changed Java 11 to Java 8 and it solved the issue. Looks like [Java 11](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11) doesn't support [SNI](https://mongodb-user.narkive.com/0kDcdKlX/atlas-python-no-sni-name-sent-make-sure-using-a-mongodb-3-4-driver-shell). Because all attempts were unsuccessful despite the fact that I used the latest drivers.

**Java 11**

Thanks to [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59129840/8370915) by Virg, I've changed version of Java 11, but also the license. I had Java 11 using [Java Development Kit builds (from Oracle)](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11) - as sourse. Then I've installed another license as [Azulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk) using JDK version 11.0.5+10 and it also solved the error.

Comment: I suspect that this is the issue you ran into: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211806

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue using a Docker image from `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.1.13-alpine-slim`. Since I've upgraded to `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.5.10-alpine-slim`, my connection to MongoDB is OK.