# Cant Connect to MongoDB Atlas - Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to create a simple REST API and have it connected to MongoDB Atlas. Whenever I run it and make a call I get a no SNI name error. I have tried looking online but I could not figure out what was wrong. this is what I currently have:

I keep getting the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.' on server cluster0-shard-00-01-ad9oa.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:398) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:136) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:728) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:725) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:463) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:725) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:89) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:189) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2793) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2532) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2515) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:876) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:380) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:204) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.example.demo.Service.PersonService.getAll(PersonService.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.Controller.PersonController.getAll(PersonController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

This is how my application properties looks like

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://tayeb:<Password-Removed>@cluster0-ad9oa.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database=Test
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.Controller;

import com.example.demo.Service.PersonService;
import com.example.demo.models.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String create(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String age) {
        Person p = personService.create(firstName, lastName, age);
        return p.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/get")
    public Person getPerson(@RequestParam String firstName) {
        return personService.getByFirstName(firstName);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Person> getAll(){
        return personService.getAll();
    }
    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String update(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String age) {
        Person p = personService.update(firstName, lastName, age);
        return p.toString();
    }
    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@RequestParam String firstName) {
        personService.delete(firstName);
        return "Deleted "+firstName;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/deleteAll")
    public String deleteAll() {
        personService.deleteAll();
        return "Deleted all records";
    }

}
```

Model

```
package com.example.demo.models;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Person {

    @Id
    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String age;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }




    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String age){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.demo.Repository;


import com.example.demo.models.Person;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>
{
    public Person findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Person> findByAge(int age);
}
```

Service

```
package com.example.demo.Service;


import com.example.demo.Repository.PersonRepository;
import com.example.demo.models.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    //Create operation
    public Person create(String firstName, String lastName, String age) {
        return personRepository.save(new Person(firstName, lastName, age));
    }
    //Retrieve operation
    public List<Person> getAll(){
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Person getByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }
    //Update operation
    public Person update(String firstName, String lastName, String age) {
        Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        p.setLastName(lastName);
        p.setAge(age);
        return personRepository.save(p);
    }
    //Delete operation
    public void deleteAll() {
        personRepository.deleteAll();
    }
    public void delete(String firstName) {
        Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        personRepository.delete(p);
    }

}
```

main

```
 package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }


}
```

These are all the files associated with my program. I would really appreciate any help

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: @komatiraju032 I believe the project is using Java 11

Comment: may be this will solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/59129840/9050514

Comment: @komatiraju032 that solved the issue! looks like java 11 is not supported..... thank you so much!