# Spring Data MongoDB connection to Mongo Atlas throws 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell' error

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I started a fresh new Kotlin + Spring Boot project. In here I'd love to connect to my Mongo Atlas cluster via Spring Data MongoDB.

I setup the configuration that is quite simple via `application.properties` (placeholders were defined):

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://backend:<password>@my-cluster.kluqx.gcp.mongodb.net/<db_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin
```

### The problem:

The following exception is thrown when the app is starting:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.' on server my-cluster-shard-00-02.kluqx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]
...
```

### My tries so far:

- I downloaded a new JDK 11 to be sure I have the proper base (from: https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11) and by suggestion of this thread ([MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112124/mongocommandexception-command-failed-with-error-8000-atlaserror-no-sni-name))
- I changed to JDK 1.8 just to try things
- I changed the mongourl style (between then driver 3.6 and above) - did not help
- I saw in this question [How to connect Mongodb Atlas to Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398285/how-to-connect-mongodb-atlas-to-spring) that someone used the *non-starter* dependency for spring boot. However this did not automatically detected by mongo stuff which is not how I wanted to develop this
- I tried to debug what the mongo driver is doing but... meh had no idea what is going wrong

**These are my dependencies regarding to this task:**

```
// shortened to the relevant parts
plugins {
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "9.3.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.3.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2")
    implementation("com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.2.4")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**: My drivers are the following according to Gradle:

```
org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.0.5
org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.0.5
```

You also can see that in the exception mentioned above where the stacktrace is related to `~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]`

Comment: So what is your driver version?

Comment: Also get this working using driver only without spring boot etc.

Comment: @D.SM Please check EDIT 1

Comment: Try  a different java runtime, maybe docker with a different OS, and do a simple test with the driver.

Comment: @D.SM Tried 1.8, 11 and 14 now - no luck. Maybe I have to find another way with the driver :(

Comment: Atlas shared tier requires SNI. You can try M10 or bigger cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The problem really was the JDK. I changed it to 14 at every place!

- Project Structure Modules and Project
- Gradle
- build.gradle file